# xml layout in android Eclipse cant find recyclerview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-recyclerview

i added recyclerview.jar and cardview.jar in my project,but just IDE in java file can recognize and read
recyclerview.in xml layout it cant find it :(
[recyclerview in java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4uDI.png)

[here you see cant find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24qbN.png)

Comment: even if it can't find it, when you write it does the code compile? IDEs are not perfect, eclipse especially, the code might still compile and the IDE can catch up after build

Comment: no,IDE cant compile it,when i run the app,shows me message that your application has stoped

Comment: in graphical layout this message showed:The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path like `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:scrollbars="vertical" />`